# Can or will Rebol run on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, arm, rebol

I have an iPhone, an Ipad, don't have yet windows phone 7, but will get it right now if rebol can run on windows phone 7 so does/will rebol support it :)

Note: rebol could run on windows mobile so my question : will it continue to run on next version ?

Well if they don't release NDK, I will buy a tablet with classic Windows 7, that for sure can run rebol and a bunch of softwares I already have :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the ARM core library will be compiled, it may be possible for someone to port the host-kit to many new hand-held devices including  Windows Phone 7, Android and even the iPhone (since they relaxed their TOS).

The ARM library is already high on the wish list of many people who are willing and able to work on the host-kit part of REBOL 3.

With 5 host-kit platforms already maintained by different developers (some indie) already at different levels of completion, the answer is not *IF* but rather *WHEN* will R3 run on these new exciting devices.

IMHO R3 still needs a little more stability work for mass porting, but in the last 2 months, I think R3 has matured to levels that are starting to catch up to R2 in many areas.

One good thing is that the extension API is proving to be highly effective and fast.  Its design is also stabilizing which is a good sign of the current maturity of the host-kit.

**A caveat**
One must understand that many mobile platforms have strict development licenses and some even have hard to integrate APIs into which executables must try and link in.

Many don't even want binaries to work directly and the road to integration isn't meant to be easy on purpose.  AFAIK winphone7 is probably the easiest one of the bunch, so don't despair.

Comment: Just having _any_ ARM library will hardly help. Winphone7 is after all a Windows CE system, so you'll need an ARM library targeting Windows CE (PE/COFF) for which in turn you'll need a toolchain. As Microsoft so far has not confirmed any plans to release such a toolchain (aka NDK) you'll need to look some place else. Those issues will certainly shake out over time, but until then, it's currently _far_ more likely to see R3 libs/builds for Android or the IPhone than for WP7.

Answer (score 1):

Not until Microsoft or a third party releases a "native development kit" (NDK). The same problem hampers others, [such as Firefox](http://www.engadget.com/2010/03/23/mozilla-halts-firefox-development-for-windows-mobile-wont-offe/), who cannot readily port their apps to Silverlight, XNA or the .NET CF (which are the only Microsoft-supported development platforms at the moment).